# move all values of a field to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to move all values of a field named CONTENT_VALUE to an array variable. Now I caught the error json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

[image]

```
while($fet_pic=mysql_fetch_array($albpic))
       {
         $album[]=$fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'];
         $bulk=json_decode($album);
       }
```

Comment: Are you sure the column is named `CONTENT_VALUE`, not `content_Value`? Can you show us the query?

Comment: Why are you using `$bulk=json_decode($album);` anyway? `$album[]=$fet_pic['content_value'];` will produce a nice array holding all `content_values`'s ....

Comment: yeah I named my field as CONTENT_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Just set the second parameter to true in the json_decode function:

```
//...
$bulk=json_decode($fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'], true);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just decode the JSON field before appending it to the array:

```
while( $fet_pic = mysql_fetch_array($albpic) )
    $album[] = json_decode( $fet_pic['CONTENT_VALUE'] );
```